# performSegue() works to show (push) either of two UIViewControllers, but one has nil navigationController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have a UIViewController that is in a navigation stack.  There are two different segues that can be triggered from this UIViewController using:

`performSegue(withIdentifier: "SomeIdentifier", sender: self)`

There are two different identifiers to show (push) either of two different subclasses of UIViewController onto the navigation stack.

In both cases, the shown (pushed) view controller appears correctly and mostly functions correctly, except that in one case the view controller has a `nil` `navigationController`.  Of course this prevents several functions from being available (eg, I cannot control the standard navigation controller toolbar from this view controller).

As far as I can tell, I'm doing the same thing in both segues, and in both UIViewController subclasses (in every way that is relevant).  The two segues are both configured in a Storyboad as "Show (eg, Push)" segues.  They both have identifiers that are called by the performSegue() (which clearly work, as they load up their correct view controllers).  They both use similar code in the `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` function.  Relevant code is below.

```
    @objc func handleButtonAction() {
//      performSegue(withIdentifier: "Profile Chart", sender: self)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Feature Geometry", sender: self)
    }
```

Comment out one of those `performSegue()` lines and uncomment the other to try the other segue:

```
    @objc func handleButtonAction() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Profile Chart", sender: self)
//      performSegue(withIdentifier: "Feature Geometry", sender: self)
    }
```

Preparing for segue (for either of the two segues):

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let geometryController = segue.destination as? FeatureGeometryController {
            geometryController.feature = feature
        } else if let profileController = segue.destination as? ProfileChartController {
            profileController.feature = feature
        }
    }
```

In the `ProfileChartController`, everything is fine.  In the `FeatureGeometryController` most things work fine.  The `feature` is assigned correctly, and its data displays correctly.  But its `navigationController` is nil (as determined below), so there is some functionality that I just can't access (include managing the standard toolbar, and calling the root view controller of the navigation controller).

In the `FeatureGeometryController`, the print statement in `viewDidLoad()` below displays `navigationController:  nil`.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("navigationController:  \(String(describing: navigationController))")
```

I have literally dozens of similar segues to/from dozens of custom UIViewController subclasses in this navigation stack, and this is the only one that has this issue.  I cannot see what I'm doing differently with this one.

What am I missing?  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'd be grateful if the person/people who have voted this down and voted to close would add a comment to detail what the perceived problem(s) are.  Otherwise I'm in the dark.  How can I improve if you will not explain what the problem is?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved!  This was very obscure (at least to me!):

As can be seen in the `prepare()` function in the question, the following property gets set:  `geometryController.feature = feature`.

This property had a `didSet{}` block in the `FeatureGeometryController` (the segue's destination) which included this line:  `tableView.tableHeaderView = someUILabel`

It seems that having this code in this `didSet{}` block must be wrong I' not sure why.  It seems that the view is loaded OK at this point (because this did actually work... the label did appear nicely as the header of the table view.)

In any case, the solution was to move this line out of the `didSet{}` block and into the `viewDidLoad()` function.

It's unclear to me why it caused this particular bad behaviour.  I would be interested in an explanation, if anybody has one.